# Gimp wouldn't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, gimp

Gimp shows this splash screen

[image]

then for a fraction of a second the program shows up in the Task manager and disappears. Tried to reinstall it but nothing's changed.

Comment: how did you install gimp? Afaik, the version from the [Ubuntu repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gimp) is **2.8.22**, while the version from the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) is **2.10.6**. Maybe you used the wrong ppa ([this here](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp-edge) has 2.99)

Comment: Next time, for screenshots or other images please use the free Imgur service which is included in the "write answer" editor. Only then we can make sure the content will be kept over time. Thank you.

Comment: @Takkat Thanks for the edit! I tried to do it via imgur several times, but it strangely wouldn't upload.

Comment: No idea what went wrong... maybe your FB link was not accepted? I downloaded the image and uploaded it from my local machine.

Comment: @Takkat That's what I did — uploaded jpg from the local machine. Probably there was some temporary problem.

Comment: In the future if you can launch gimp from the command line instead of a gui it will give you errors on that command line. That can often be more helpful than a picture of a loading bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Gimp version shown in the splash screen I assume you use the [gimp-edge](https://launchpad.net/%7Eotto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp-edge) ppa, which is probably not the one you want.

In the description it states:

> Attention!
>
> This is a PPA only for development purposes!!!

Better to use the ["normal" ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eotto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp).

---

Try this to fix,

```bsh
# Install ppa-purge
sudo apt install ppa-purge
# Remove the *wrong* ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
# Remove the OS gimp package if it was installed
sudo apt remove gimp

# Add the *right* ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

# Update sources and install gimp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! (Cannot remember adding this strange repo though)
Please, correct apt-purge → ppa-purge (I cannot edit your answer)

Comment: glad it helped. Sure, `ppa-purge` ...